# Top navbar to go underneath side navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using the example from bootstrap called 'dashboard' I'm wanting to get the top navbar to actually tuck underneath the side navbar. Like this example: [Image Example from Dribbble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lImfU.png)

I've put the dashboard code from bootstrap onto jsfiddle for ease of use for those that are willing to help (I really appreciate any help with this).
https://jsfiddle.net/1dy65wqx/

It should impact this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reports</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed few styles, please add this to your css file..

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative;">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar" style="position:fixed; z-index:2000; top:0px;">
```